# one or more phone numbers for every user

Tags: database, database-design

I am making a `user` entity here, there are some things that are not clear to me. So I have an attribute `phoneNo` that user may have one or more phone numbers , so if I need something like that do I make a new entity `phoneNumber` and have a `phoneNo` as PK ? Also similar thing with customers where customer can either be regular or premium , do I have to make a new entity CustomerType ? I didnt want to make a new entity for isAdmin because it can be either off or on ? would this be ok...

this is what I am talking about

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a given attribute may have multiple values, use a separate table. Your `isAdmin` attribute probably can have only one scalar value, which may be true or false.

I would expect the reference in that diagram to go the other way. That is, `User` may have multiple `phoneNumber`s, so you should make `phoneNumber` reference `User`. And then you would not need a column `phoneNo` in the `User` table.

The diagram you have shows the opposite relationship, in which a `phoneNumber` could have multiple `User`s.

The direction of the reference for `CustomerType` is consistent with what I would expect it to be. That is, there may be multiple `User`s with a given `CustomerType`.

Comment: basically you are saying just take out the phoneNo from the user table  ? thats what I actually had when I started making this table , and I started thinking too much...thanks for pointing out the cardinality